# How can I properly wrap complex objects?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I'm having problems with the Shrinkwrap modifier. I wanna wrap this dragon on the objects surface.

[image: I wanna wrap this dragon on the objects surface]

But instead I get this :(

[image]

I've tried with Curve too...

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks... And sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: use another modifier, like Curve for example

Comment: well I'm not sure about the result, even with a Curve or another modifier, I guess it will greatly depends on the topology of your dragon object. Perhaps the most reasonable would be to texture your object with this illustration and give it a bit of relief with a Bump or Normal node?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A30601+shrinkwrap

Comment: I need to do a printable object, I dont know if a texture will help :(

Comment: I've already used Curve, but didnt work.

Comment: You should also look for an addon that does this.  The curve started to work in your diagram ... change the curve and try again.   Align the origins of mesh and curve for different results.  You should also show a complete picture of the mesh and container because there is too much guess work in seeing your pictures.  Please state if you are making progress a little or a lot.

Comment: Have your tried tinkering around with the settings on the shrinkwrap modifier? Sometimes certain settings work better than the default. I'd also suggest from the previous comment that there could be an addon for that.